# When and When Not to @import .js files

Tags: javascript, file, import, include

I've recently learn that it's possible to `@import` `.js` files in a manner similar to `css` files (see [S.O. Q/A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/22396258#22396258)).

Now the task of knowing when and when *not* to `@import`.

It seems answer's a matter of the pros/cons between number of page requests and size of the requests. Should only large `.js` files be added to pages conditionally and smaller ones globally imported? If so, what is a good general file-size cut-off limit?

**An example:**
Should a script like [Fit Vids .js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) (which unminified is `2.698 kb`) be included via `@import` for a site that only has videos on *some* pages? Or should it be conditionally added (via manual methods or dynamic logic - is there any such script to conditionally load `.js`?) for only pages with videos?

Comment: `@import` can only be done with `.js` via a framework such as [**mixture**](http://docs.mixture.io/preprocessors), not with plain vanilla js

Comment: right, but even if using a different method (many are given in [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/)) to achieve the same results, the question of "when and when not to?" still remains.

Comment: what do you mean specifically? injecting scripts onto the page as opposed to including them via `<script></script>` ?

Comment: no, not injecting vs including. I mean combining into *one* global script file vs including via *multiple* script files (all using `<script></script>`)

Comment: more scripts per url=better gzip perf, but it would be nice to fire domcomplete without loading more than 100kb...

Comment: hmm..."more scripts per url=better gzip perf" seems a bit counter-intuitive (at least to someone with primarily `css` experience). Are you saying that it's best to have multiple `.js` files so long as their totaled size is `< 100kb`? If so, perhaps you could include this as an answer with some supporting resources?